# Format String with Trailing Space

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some doubles that I want to format as strings so that they look like this:

```
   $ 123.00
($ 3,231.99)
     $ 0.82
```

So basically I need to get the positive doubles to print with a single trailing space.  Here is the string formatted:

```
Value1.ToString("$ #,0.00 ;($ #,0.00);$ 0.00 ");
```

However, when they are being printed, on the web page the trailing space is not included.  What am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps use a non-breaking space (&nbsp;) or a CSS white-space style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the non-breaking space character in your string. To do that, use unicode

```
\u00A0
```

Example:

```
string a = "b\u00A0cd"
```

Will be printed as:

```
b cd
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `&nbsp;` for the space.  Trailing spaces are not displayed by HTML.

Comment: This sounds promising - would you know how to correctly insert a non-breaking space into my format string?  It's not working...