# Include HTML in Numeric .ToString() Format

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, string-formatting

See [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35818941/asp-net-mvc-format-string-with-trailing-space/35821956#35821956) for some background.  I am effectively trying to get the following to line up:

```
   $ 123.00
($ 3,231.99)
     $ 0.82
```

I have got it close by inserting a unicode nbsp into the format string.  However, the nbsp is not the EXACT same width as a perenthesis.

Is there any way that I could include HTML in a format string and have it be interpreted correctly?  I am using ASP.NET MVC with the Razor ViewEngine.

I am currently converting these with something like this:

```
Value.ToString("$ #,0.00;($ #,0.00);");
```

I added a nbsp like this (which is pretty close):

```
Value.ToString("$ #,0.00\u00A0;($ #,0.00);");
```

I am thinking something like this to make it align perfectly with every font:

```
Value.ToString("$ #,0.00<span class='color:transparent;'>)</span>;($ #,0.00;");
```

Thoughts?

Comment: You should `right-alight` your values in a specific width element AND change the font to a fixed width font.  Any other attempt using non-blocking spaces or whatever will rarely yield the results you are looking for.

Comment: All of my numbers are fixed width already...just not some of the characters...  there has got to be a way of doing this with any font - it's such an easy thing to do with an Excel format string...

Answer (score 2):

To actually solve the problem, I would just use tables.  The nice part about this solution is that all the columns will have equal widths.

```css
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  }
table tr td{
  text-align: right
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>$</td>
    <td>123.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>(</td>
    <td>$</td>
    <td>3,231.99</td>
    <td>)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>$</td>
    <td>0.82</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Not a bad idea - this would work for some of my scenarios - except I need to do the formatting via a numeric format string because I want to format my DevExpress controls in the same way - I'm sure there is a way to make it work by including HTML in a format string I think I'm just missing something...

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to multi column table answer, you can use a monospace font and right text align for your numeric columns and then the space at the end of positive numbers should align correctly with the right paren of the negative numbers.

Here are examples of monospace font families. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp

"Courier New", Courier, monospace

"Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace

Note: searching the Internet may lead you to `<TD align="char" char="." >`. Do NOT use this align=char option, as it is not supported in HTML5.

Comment: Yea - that would be an okay option in a simpler scenario - but I am pretty attached to the font that I am using - also Monospace fonts tend to be sooo ugly -